# What kind of calculation does tf.nn.dynamic_rnn do with its input parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

What kind of calculation does [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) perform? How does it use the parameters `cell` and `inputs` (to create the result)?

I have looked up in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), but I have not found an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `tf.nn.static_rnn` vs. `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`

Internally, `tf.nn.static_rnn` creates an unrolled graph for a fixed RNN length. That means that, if you call `tf.nn.static_rnn` with inputs having 200 time-steps you are creating a static graph with 200 RNN steps. First, graph creation is slow. Second, you’re unable to pass in longer sequences (> 200) than you've originally specified.

`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` solves this. It uses a `tf.while_loop` to dynamically construct the graph when it is executed. That means graph creation is faster and you can feed batches of variable size.

#### What about performance?

You may think the `tf.nn.static_rnn` is faster than its dynamic counterpart because it pre-builds the graph.

> Please note, it is strongly encouraged to use `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

Reference: http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sorry, that doesn't answer my question. I didn't ask a difference between RNN and Dynamic_RNN.

Comment: the difference actually answers your question. calculation of dynamic rnn is similar to a simple rnn and the only difference is mentioned in my answer. if you don't understand, read the reference blog post CAREFULLY.